# fixed-top class of bootstrap menu is not working on large devices in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, menu, css-position

I am using bootstrap class 'navbar-fixed-top' class in order to get the navbar to stick to the top of the window, such as in this example:

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Following is menu code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Awesome Theme</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <?php 
                wp_nav_menu(array(
                    'theme_location' => 'primary',
                    'container' => false,
                    'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
                    'walker' => new Walker_Nav_Primary()
                    )
                );
                ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Following is screenshot of menu on large device (not visible properly)
[image]

Menu works on medium devices as in the following screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use css codes for screen sizes such as:

```
@media (min-width: 979px) {

    .navbar { ... }

}
```

Combine max-width property of CSS to achieve what you need. 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp

Comment: should i set  max-width?

Comment: You can say that if minimum width of the device is let say 979 px, then set my navbar class' max-width to 900px for example.

Comment: Are you using true class names, true syntax or logical width checks?

Comment: i am using this code @media (min-width: 968px) {

     .navbar{
   max-width: 100%;
 }

}   but still not working

Comment: Because  "max-width: 100%" is making your navbar's width 100% of the screen. You should specify it as px such as "max-width: 960px".

Comment: by the way its working on Firefox but not working on chrome?

Comment: Browser compatibility is another topic. You can search browser compatabilities at : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp